# MVC: Model is missing from cshtml intellisense

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am doing some sample MVC project in .net. For some reason, Model is missing in my visual studio intellisense. I have no idea what am I missing here. Please help me to find out the reason here.

Controller:

```
public class EmployeeController : Controller
{
    PersonalDetails personalDetails;

    public EmployeeController()
    {
        personalDetails = new PersonalDetails();
    }

    public ActionResult Employee()
    {
        return View("Employee", personalDetails.Employee(1));
    }
}
```

Model:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@model EmployeeModel.Employee 

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Employee";
}

<select id="name">
@foreach (var item in Model.ID)//Model is not coming here.
{
    <option value="value">@item</option>
}
```

[image: Model]

Comment: make sure all your assembly references are intact and build soultion and try again .

Comment: reference structure should be `@model projectname.models.class` then you will get Model with the respective properties . cheers